# Let $A$ be the annulus in $\mathbb{C}$, what is the space $A/{\sim}$ generated by identifying all points on the "inner circle" with each other?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces

The annulus is $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:1\leq |z| \leq 2\}$ and the "inner circle" here is the set of points $\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|=1\}$.

If we identify all points of the inner circle together, then, intuitively, the space is then homeomorphic to the closed disk. Is this correct?

If this is correct, how can I justify this answer beyond the observation that the quotient map has created some sort of "middle" for the annulus, thereby making it homeomorphic to the disk?

Comment: You can prove it by writing down a map $A \to D^2$, sending $re^{i\theta}$ to $(r-1)e^{i\theta}$. This has the desired properties; show that it's a quotient map.

Comment: This is really clear, thank you.